# Combinatorics - The Candies

Tags: c++, algorithm, dynamic-programming, combinatorics

I found this problem somewhere in a contest and haven't been able to come up with a solution yet.

> The boy has apples and keeps in boxes. In one box no more than N/2.
>   How many methods he can put candies to boxes.

So what I'm trying to do is to implement solution using DP. Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstring>
#include <algorithm>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <vector>
#define size 1002
using namespace std;

long long a[size][size];
int n, k;
int main()
{
    cin >> n >> k;
    int kk = n/2;

    for(int i = 0; i <= k; ++i)
        a[0][i] = 1;
    a[0][0] = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i <= kk; ++i)
        a[i][1] = 1;

    for(int i = 1; i <= n; ++i) {

        for(int j = 2; j <= k; ++j) {
            int index = 0;
            long long res = 0;
            while(1) {
                res += a[i-index][j - 1];
                index += 1;

                if(index == kk + 1 || i-index < 0)
                    break;
            }
            a[i][j] = res;

        }
    }
    cout << a[n][k] << endl;

}
```

But the problem is that we have large numbers in input like:

> 2 ≤ N ≤ 1000 is a quantity of the candies, N - even; 2 ≤ S ≤ 1000 - is a quantity of small boxes.

So, for input like N = 1000 and S = 1000, I have to spent 5*10^8 operations. And the numbers are very big, so I have to use BigInteger arithmetics?

Maybe there is algorithm to implement the problem in linear time? Thanks and sorry for my English!

Comment: does your code give the correct results for smaller sized input?

Comment: @tobi303 Yes, the solution is correct for smaller input.

Comment: Have a look at the last line of [this article](http://www.mathpages.com/home/kmath337.htm) which gives a closed formula to compute the number (replace (`k`,`m`, `R`) by (`N`,`S`,`(N/2)`), resp.).

Comment: I guess "In one small box placed no more then N/2 of candies" is supposed to read "No small box shall have more than N/2 candies" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily decrease the time complexity from O(k*n^2) into O(n*k) by the following observation:

```
for(int i = 1; i <= n; ++i) {

    for(int j = 2; j <= k; ++j) {
        int index = 0;
        long long res = 0;
        while(1) {
            res += a[i-index][j - 1];
            index += 1;

            if(index == kk + 1 || i-index < 0)
                break;
        }
        a[i][j] = res;

    }
}
```

for each `a[i][j]`, we can easily see that

`a[i][j] = sum a[k][j - 1]` with k from `(i - n/2)` to `i`

So, if we create an array `sum` to store the sum from all indexes of the previous step, we can reduce one for loop from the above nested loop

`a[i][j] = sum[i] - sum[i - (n/2) - 1];`

Pseudo code:

```
long long sum[n + 1];
for(int j = 2; j <= k; ++j) {
    long long nxt[n + 1];
    for(int i = 1; i <= n; ++i) {
        int index = 0;
        long long res = sum[i] - sum[i - (n/2) - 1];

        a[i][j] = res;
        nxt[i] = nxt[i - 1] + a[i][j];//Prepare the sum array for next step

    }
    sum = nxt;
}
```

**Note:** This above code is not handled the initialization step for array `sum`, as well as not handle the case when i < n/2. Those cases should be obvious to handle.

Update:

My below Java solution get accepted by using similar idea:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    // PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream(new File(
    // "output.txt")));
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(System.out);
    Scanner in = new Scanner();
    int n = in.nextInt();
    int s = in.nextInt();
    BigInteger[][] dp = new BigInteger[n + 1][2];
    BigInteger[][] count = new BigInteger[2][n + 1];
    int cur = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i <= n / 2; i++) {
        dp[i][0] = BigInteger.ONE;
        count[0][i] = (i > 0 ? count[0][i - 1]  : BigInteger.ZERO)
                .add(dp[i][0]);

    }
    for (int i = n / 2 + 1; i <= n; i++) {
        dp[i][0] = BigInteger.ZERO;
        count[0][i] = count[0][i - 1];
    }
    for (int i = 2; i <= s; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j <= n; j++) {

            dp[j][cur] = dp[j][1 - cur].add((j > 0 ? count[1 - cur][j - 1]
                    : BigInteger.ZERO)
                    .subtract(j > n / 2 ? count[1 - cur][j - (n / 2) - 1]
                            : BigInteger.ZERO));

            count[cur][j] = (j > 0  ? count[cur][j - 1] : BigInteger.ZERO)
                    .add(dp[j][cur]);
        }
        cur = 1 - cur;
    }
    out.println(dp[n][1 - cur]);
    out.close();
}
```

Comment: What about the size of numbers? If I use BigIntegers arithmetics time complexity will increase again.

Comment: @James BigInteger is ok, as we only need to add/subtract, so time complexity is not significantly increased. I have submitted and get accepted by implementing a Java solution with similar idea.